# Node.js + Express: internal exception at res.sendFile(): returns undefined, can't catch the exception, delivery of file to client fails (throws 404)

Tags: node.js, http, sockets, websocket, httprequest

I'm building an https server with Node.js and Express. I use res.sendFile(path, root, onerror) to return requested files to the client. However, there seems to be an internal error in sendFile(). The script runs on without logging any error, but the file isn't sent (client throws a 404).

I can catch it as an uncaughtException, but it is undefined (I can't get the details/stack of the bug). This might be since it's an internal error of a Node.js module... ?

```
// send homepage.html from the directory the script is in
res.sendFile('homepage.html', {root: __dirname}, err=>{ if(err){ console.log(err.stack, err); process.exit(1); } }); 
// an exception occurs, but `err` in the callback is undefined. Effectively, I can't even trace the exception.
```

the sendFile() function itself returns undefined as well, instead of an object.

I have no idea what's happening. Replacing __dirname with '.' does nothing. It's not a routing issue since the sendFile() method returns undefined (so it's its internal error). It's also not likely a rights-to-fetch-files issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your full code? Are you using es-module?

```
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('homepage.html', { root: __dirname }, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack, err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
});
```

apparently this works.

If you are using es-module

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```